# Is it safe to use PUT and DELETE requests

Tags: http, rest

I am building my new shiny WordPress plugin and since I've read about REST etc.I wanted to do things right and implement PUT and DELETE requests, and not just use POST and GET like I did until now.

But now I am wondering is it safe to use those. And by safe, I mean, are those requests supported by all servers in general or is general practice to have them disabled?

I don't want to implement everything now only to figure out later that just because of my wish to follow semantics my product is unusable for half of my customers.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.  Those are standard HTTP methods, generally supported everywhere.

More info: [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The question you linked to is not really related to my question, as I am not worried by browser support but server support. And I don't mean "support" as a technical term, I understand those methods are technically supported nowadays.

If anyone else cares to provide feedback, I would be grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it safe to *write* PUT and DELETE requests?

Absolutely, if you're writing the RESTful service, and have a use for these verbs.

#### Is it *always* safe to write PUT and DELETE requests?

It depends.  You have to ensure that the server you're interfacing with supports these verbs, and if they don't, then you simply can't use them.

Bear in mind, not all HTTP servers support or use all of the verbs.  Some may elect to use a POST with a query parameter to behave as a DELETE, or do the same with a PUT.